# Filtering out data in Spark dataframe in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe df, which contains below data:

```
**customers**   **product**   **Val_id**
     1               A            1
     2               B            X
     3               C               
     4               D            Z
```

I have successfully filtered for data where column val_id is blank

```
df.where(col("val_id").isin(""))
```

But I am not able to figure out a way to filter data where column val_id is not blank, i tried something like below, but did not work for me:

```
df.where(col("val_id").isnotin(""))
```

Can anyone please help me to achieve it using Spark Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use filter to get desired output:

```
df.filter("rule_id != ''")
```

Comment: How do I collect all those rows/records from a dataframe which didn't pass this filter condition. any inbuilt methods or  else?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Val_id` is of String type, you can use this inequality operator `!==`:

```
df.where(col("Val_id") !== "").show
```

Conversely, you can also use `===` for matching the blank.

Comment: How do I collect all those rows/records from a dataframe which didn't pass this filter condition. any inbuilt methods or  else?

Answer (score 0):

If column type is `String`:

```
df.where(trim(col("val_id")) != "")
```

Comment: How do I collect all those rows/records from a dataframe which didn't pass this filter condition. any inbuilt methods or  else?